# Rails 4: Where to put data migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I need to fix some data inconsistencies in our database, and I'm not so sure if it's considered a bad practice putting that code as a migration (in `db/migrations`). Is there a better, more elegant way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a one-off execution ( for example backfilling a new field's default value, or changing a data-type),  I suggest db/migrations for two reasons :

1. you dont want that code to be executed a second time.
2. you can script a rolled back if necessary ( e.g. `self.down`)

Alternatively, if the script is auditing your data systematically, and new data could potentially have these inconstencies. A rake task would be desirable so you can periodically execute the script.